# media format (payloadtype number) in media line is different from the rtpmap

Tags: sip, sdp

While testing SIP Video call,  I am getting the below the media line information in an answer for an Offered media. Is this valid media line ??
where media format number is different from the rtpmap number:

```
m=video 49218 RTP/AVP 109
b=TIAS:322000
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=42801f; max-mbps=216000; max-fs=3600; sar=13
a=sendonly
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not a valid session description, but for a more subtle reason than Ralf's answer. A PT (payload type) of 109 falls in the dynamic range of the RTP/AVP profile defined in [RFC 3551](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3551) which applies because of the `RTP/AVP` in the `m` line. "Dynamic" means what it says: RTP/AVP defines a whole bunch of standard codecs - PCM mu-law, G.729, and so on - and also allows for you to define your own PTs.

Here, the description says "we're going to use a custom PT of 109, and define another at 96, and forget to define what 109 means".

It's perfectly valid to define a bunch of `rtpmap` attributes and not use them; it's not valid to use a PT and then not define it!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it's an implementation bug since the rtpmap attribute is not referencing a payload format that has been specified in the media line, which effectively renders the attribute useless.

From [Rfc4566](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566):

```
a=rtpmap:<payload type> <encoding name>/<clock rate> [/<encoding
     parameters>]

     This attribute maps from an RTP payload type number (as used in
     an "m=" line) to an encoding name denoting the payload format
     to be used.
```